# Restrict width in ConstraintLayout by another view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Is there a possibility (in `ConstraintLayout`) to let a view grow only as long as there is space for another view at his right?

The use case is to have a `value` and `unit` TextViews besides each other. The `value` TextView should be able to grow as long as there is space for the `unit`. If there is not enough space, the `value` should be cut.

[image: ConstraintLayout]

I've tried it with chains and some other things but can't get it done. The `value` doesn't stop growing and then the `unit` is not visible anymore. Here's the current code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:lines="1"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/unit"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/unit"
    tools:text="12533939532" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/unit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/value"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:text="km" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConstraintLayout Chains and Text Ellipsis + Image on the Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410786/constraintlayout-chains-and-text-ellipsis-image-on-the-right)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

yes you can by using **match_constraint** (0dp) which equal to match_parent for other layout, so by using **match_constraint** we set weight for first view which will occupies all available space also add

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```

to apply default width behavior as wrap_content

here is code with change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:lines="1"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/unit"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/unit"
            tools:text="12533939532" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/value"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            tools:text="km" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

got some explanation from site

**Better view dimension controls**

The new available behaviors when a dimension is set to 0dp **(MATCH_CONSTRAINT)**. As before, both endpoints (left/right or top/bottom) need to be connected to targets.

layout_constraintWidth_default = spread (default, similar to the previous behavior)
layout_constraintWidth_default = wrap
layout_constraintHeight_default = spread
layout_constraintHeight_default = wrap

**Wrap** provides a significant new behaviour, with the widget resizing as if wrap_content was used, but limited by the connected constraints. A widget will thus not grow beyond the endpoints.

http://tools.android.com/recent/constraintlayoutbeta5isnowavailable

Comment: Didn't really get your explanation, but the code works, thanks!

Comment: yeh, the main thing that layout_constraintWidth_default introduced in ConstraintLayout 1.0 to solve wrap_content problem which u was getting and there is no any official documentation for same.

Comment: @MariusBoepple updated some description got may be helpful

Comment: This works, but only in a limited way.  As long as the right-most View is lined up with `parent` (as in `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`) this is fine.  If it's up against another View, then everything gets over-written.  Sigh.