# ConstraintLayout: ellipsized text with "spring"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I try to implement layout from the picture. The problem is TextView - I need to wrap short text and ellipsize long one at the same time, but just can't achieve this:

1. `layout_width="wrap_content"` - wrap is OK, but of course ellipsize is NOT (because no constraints applied, when wrap_content used)
2. `layout_width="0dp"` - wrap not working
3. `layout_width="0dp"` + `constraintWidth_default="wrap"` - wrap is OK, ellipsize is NOT

Also tried to play with `constrainedWidth="true"`, but had no any visible effect.

[image]

Comment: The icon here is drawableEnd or an imageView?

Comment: @Kartik ImageView, this is why I need that "wrap" behavior

Comment: You can have `layout_width="wrap_content"` and give `maxWidth` programmatically after calculation. This way you can achieve this.

Comment: @Kartik found solution using ConstraintLayout only, if you're interested — look to the answer below

Answer (score 3):

Oh, did it! I used solution for similar problem ([ConstraintLayout Chains and Text Ellipsis + Image on the Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410786/constraintlayout-chains-and-text-ellipsis-image-on-the-right)) - it won't help **until I excluded `Button` from the chain and remove `Space` which I used as "spring"**!

Here is result - works exactly as in the picture.

```
<ConstraintLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  ...>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="0dp" // enable constraints
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed" // keep text + icon side by side
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0" // move text + icon to the left
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap" // make text as small to wrap text
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" // chain starts
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/icon" // chain continues
    .../>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/text" // chain continues
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button" // chain ENDS!
    .../>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" // move button to the right
    // PAY ATTENTION! There is no constraintLeft_toRightOf="icon" attribute!
    // because button must be out of chain
    .../>

</ConstraintLayout>
```